# Removing file extension in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, file-extension

How can I remove the extension file in asp.net something like `filename.jpg` to `filename`? I tried searching some reference but all I find is URL extension only

Comment: Here you go: http://forums.asp.net/t/1969350.aspx?Help+with+removing+file+extension

Answer (score 1):

Use the [System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

The return value for this method is the string returned by [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx), minus the last period (.) and all characters following it.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fuImage.FileName); //file-name
string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(fuImage.FileName); //.jpg,.png....
string path_thumb = Path.Combine("Images/", string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", fileName, "-" + datetime + "-thumb", fileExt)); //full  path: Images/file-name-012345-thumb.jpg
```